# Regex match first word differently

Tags: javascript, regex

This regex matches strings that start with capital letters.

```
var str = "THISIsTheStringToSplit".match(/[A-Z]+[a-z]*/g);
```

However if the string starts with lowercase letter I want to it to be part of the first word. e.g.

```
  var str = "testTHISIsTheStringToSplit".match(/[A-Z]+[a-z]*/g);
```

So the first match should be "testTHISIs"

How should I modify the regex to allow this case?

Comment: Your regex already has a "lowercase" part. How about moving it around, duplicate it, ... Try something on your own...

Comment: You are right but I wasn't sure how to make this conditionally only for the first part. Thanks!

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Both the links don't give same result for `THISIsTheStringToSplit` as in this question/answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allow matching 0 or more lowercase letters at the start before matching 1+ uppercase letters:

```
/[a-z]*[A-Z]+[a-z]*/g
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rDmPIf/1)

```js
const arr = ['THISIsTheStringToSplit', 'testTHISIsTheStringToSplit']

const re = /[a-z]*[A-Z]+[a-z]*/g;

arr.forEach(s =>
  console.log(s, s.match(re))
)
```

Comment: But I do see an attempted regex in question from OP that is not working in intended way.